# Statistical Mechanics: Most probable orientation of grain particle in gas chamber?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, probability, statistics

I'm in an introductory statistical mechanics course, and we've been posed the following situation:

Long-shaped dust particle (so imagine something like a grain of rice) is placed in a gas chamber (so I suppose there is a gas inside). System is at temperature T. The long axis of the particle is set towards the z-axis (vertical) as a simple initial condition.

Question: What is the most probable orientation the dust particle will have as time passes?

That's all we were given. How would one approach answering the question? Here's how I initially answered it:

I based my answer on the idea that Nature prefers lower energy and higher entropy always for equilibrium/stability. So even if we imagine the dust particle being hit time to time by gas particles that cause it to spin, the most probable orientation would still be that which is the most stable, hence the one with lower energy.

I then reason that the orientation with the lowest energy would be any orientation on the x-y plane (horizontal), as any location on the particle would then have the same gravitational potential energy. No matter how small it is, I reason that placing the particle in any other orientation provides one end a higher potential energy than the other, which is thus against the rule of increasing entropy and decreasing energy. Thus the most probable orientation is the horizontal one.

Does anyone have any other answers? If anyone has a more mathematical answer (if there is one), that would be wonderful.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: You should put your ideas which you said you have in your question.

Comment: Didn't place them so others would be able to give answers without prior influence, but if you're suspecting I haven't tried thinking for myself, then okay:

Comment: Don't worry about influencing.  Right now it looks like you just want an answer for something from a university course.  If you write down your thoughts, it looks like you worked for some kind of solution, and people will more likely respond.  Edit your post with your thoughts.

Comment: Here:

I based my answer on the idea that Nature prefers lower energy and higher entropy always for equilibrium/stability. So even if we imagine the dust particle being hit time to time by gas particles that cause it to spin, the most probable orientation would still be that which is the most stable, hence the one with lower energy.

Comment: I then reason that the orientation with the lowest energy would be any orientation on the x-y plane (horizontal), as any location on the particle would then have the same gravitational potential energy. No matter how small it is, I reason that placing the particle in any other orientation provides one end a higher potential energy than the other, which is thus against the rule of increasing entropy and decreasing energy. Thus the most probable orientation is the horizontal one.

Comment: Ah very nice...  one comment about your answer: believe it or not, the horizontal orientation has the same gravitational potential energy as the vertical orientation.  The top part of the grain (higher potential energy) exactly balances the bottom part of the grain (lower potential energy), so that it is equal to the horizontal configuration.  Draw a picture and you'll see.

Comment: Yup, thought about that. But I was thinking having a uniform distributed potential would be more stable than other configurations. Would that be right?

Comment: I give your teacher +5 for asking an open-ended question like this.   I suspect xe's looking for how you solve it and how you justify your solution, rather than demanding a specific "correct" answer.

Comment: @user42189 no, stability is determined by just the value of the integrated potential; not how it is distributed.

Comment: That's where I get stumped then. I'm not sure how else to remedy this solution, or what other possibilities to consider.